# How to optimize SQL with WHERE and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, index, optimization

I have the SQL statement:

```
SELECT erp_orders_id
FROM erp_orders o
WHERE o.orders_export_time >= '2015-09-20'
ORDER BY o.erp_orders_id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

where `erp_orders_id` is primary key of type int. and `orders_export_time` is `timestamp`.
I'm trying to optimize it by creating an index on both `orders_export_time` and `erp_orders_id`:

```
ALTER TABLE `erp_orders` 
ADD KEY `IDX_ORDERID_EXPORTTIME`(`erp_orders_id`,`orders_export_time`) USING BTREE;
```

However, `EXPLAIN` shows it chooses `PRIMARY` to filter data:

```
+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------------+---------------+-------------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+
| id           | select_type           | table           | type           | possible_keys           | key           | key_len           | ref           | rows           | Extra           |
+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------------+---------------+-------------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+
| 1            | SIMPLE                | o               | index          | orders_export_time      | PRIMARY       | 4                 |               | 5              | Using where     |
+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------------+---------------+-------------------+---------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

## QUESTIONS

**1 : I don't understand why primary is chosen here?**

So I tried to force using index `IDX_ORDERID_EXPORTTIME` and get the following plan which seems good to me:

```
+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------------+------------------------+-------------------+---------------+----------------+--------------------------+
| id           | select_type           | table           | type           | possible_keys           | key                    | key_len           | ref           | rows           | Extra                    |
+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------------+------------------------+-------------------+---------------+----------------+--------------------------+
| 1            | SIMPLE                | o               | index          |                         | IDX_ORDERID_EXPORTTIME | 8                 |               | 1              | Using where; Using index |
+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------+----------------+-------------------------+------------------------+-------------------+---------------+----------------+--------------------------+
```

With the plan above, I assume it would be much faster than the first query. However, when I execute it, it runs pretty slow, even slower than the first one. So

**2 : Why is this query so slow even with execution plan indicates that it scanned only 1 row?**

**3 : How am I supposed to optimize this query?**

Comment: Change the order of columns in your index, if `orders_export_time` is the 1st column it can be used.

Comment: @dnoeth I tried to add the index as you said. it still uses `PRIMARY` scan. If I force using this index, there would be 2359832 rows scanned according to the plan. any idea why?

Comment: I would try it as two separate indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No single index (composite or not) will be optimal

```
WHERE x > ...
ORDER BY y
```

You can provide both of these, and let the Optimizer pick:

```
INDEX(x) -- filters out unwanted rows, but you are left with a sort
INDEX(y) -- avoids sort, but does no filtering
```

On the other hand, this would be a "covering" index for that *specific* query:

```
INDEX(orders_export_time, erp_orders_id)
```

and might be better than putting them in the opposite order.

Comment: So do you mean when there is a range condition, the index can't cover both `WHERE` and `ORDER`?

Comment: One composite INDEX _can_ handle both -- but _only if_ the `WHERE` is just a bunch of "column = constant" clauses `ANDed` together.  Your use of ">=" makes that impossible.

Answer (score 0):

> Q1: I don't understand why primary is chosen here?

The index you made helps neither the `WHERE` or the `ORDER BY` due to the columns in the wrong order.

Since you selected only the `erp_orders_id`, the `PRIMARY KEY` was chosen.

> Q2: Why is this query so slow even with execution plan indicates that it scanned only 1 row?

Since you forced the index, the entire index was scanned until one row was found that matched `o.orders_export_time >= '2015-09-20'`. If you have rows from earlier months, even earlier years, those rows would be read until `'2015-09-20'` was finally found.

> Q3 how am I supposed to optimize this query?

As [@dnoeth said in the comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117754/how-to-optimize-sql-with-where-and-order-by#comment214669_117754), reverse the column order in the index.

```
ALTER TABLE `erp_orders` 
ADD KEY `IDX_ORDERID_EXPORTTIME`(`orders_export_time`,`erp_orders_id`) USING BTREE;
```

Comment: I tried to add this index. Somehow, mysql still thinks PRIMARY is still the best choice. I can force using the `IDX_ORDERID_EXPORTTIME`, but it would scan 2359832 rows to get result. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Effective indexes have in the `INDEX KEY COLUMNS` the column names that are used for row restriction and processing; those columns in the `WHERE, JOIN, ORDER BY, GROUP BY`:

This would be from your example `orders_export_time`.

If more than 1 column in needed here, they should be added in order from top to bottom by those that will be the MOST restrictive - the column that will reduce your overall results by the largest amount of records.  For example, if you had columns `FIRST_NAME` and `LAST_NAME` in your key columns, `LAST_NAM`E would most likely go first as it would reduce your results more than a first name would.

Then, in the `INCLUDED COLUMNS` tab, you add your column names that are in your SELECT.  (This is why trying to index a `SELECT * FROM` could never truly be indexed well.  It'd just be too large and inefficient).

This would be from your example `erp_orders_id`.

Always keep in mind though that the `PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED INDEX` on your table is always already automatically included by default in every other non-clustered index's `INCLUDED COLUMNS`, so other than helping to visualize all pieces of an index, if "`erp_orders_id`" is your `PRIMARY CLUSTERED INDEX` on the table already, putting it into the include is not necessary.  Adding your `PRIMARY CLUSTERED INDEX` column name into another non-clustered index's `INDEX KEY COLUMNS` is not recommended, bloats your table, and increases your index/statistics maintenance.

`Index FILLFACTOR` is another topic, but should be considered when creating any new index.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ name your index here ] ON [dbo].[erp_orders]
(
    [orders_export_time] ASC
)
INCLUDE ([erp_orders_id]) 
WITH(FILLFACTOR = ?)
```

Comment: MySQL does not have `INCLUDE` columns.